# How To SetFieldChangeListener for ListField in Blackberry?

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, listfield

I am new For Blackberry .. i need some Help. How To SetFieldChangeListener for ListField  in Blackberry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```
yourListField.setChangeListener(fieldChangeListenerInterfaceImplementation);
```

Implement [FieldChangeListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FieldChangeListener.html) and pass the implementation instance to [setChangeListener()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setChangeListener%28net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener%29);

Comment: Use search on StackOverflow, use search on Google. And you will find sample code for FieldChangeListener.

Answer (score 1):

```
listField = new ListField() {
        protected boolean invokeAction(int action) {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {

                    <** apply your code here **>                    

                    }
                });
                return true;
            };

            public void focusChangeNotify(int index) {
                mainlist = listField.getSelectedIndex();
                listField.invalidate();
                super.focusChangeNotify(index);
            };

            protected void onUnfocus() {
                mainlistflag = true;
                listField.invalidate();
                super.onUnfocus();
            };

            protected void onFocus(int direction) {

                mainlistflag = false;
                super.onFocus(direction);

            };
        };
```